# google maps draw circle from

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need to draw a circle in google Maps V3 but I have 2 coordinates, the center and the outter position. Problem is the API expects center and "radius".
For example:

```
var myCirclePath = [];
myCirclePath.push(new google.maps.LatLng(18.111111,66.111111));
myCirclePath.push(new google.maps.LatLng(18.223344,66.222222));

var myCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
    center: myCirclePath[0],
    radius: // what do I put here????
    map: map
});
```

I searched around the web and find a lot of stuff about radians, degrees, sin, atan, and what not... however, I'm not good at math and I'm totally lost.

So, the questions are:

a) What should I put in the "radius:" option?

b) How can I center the zoom around the circle? "Bounds.Extend" will not do it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So, the questions are:
>
> a) What should I put in the "radius:" option?

Use the [geometry library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry#Distance) computeDistanceBetween() to find the radius (passing in your two points)

> b) How can I center the zoom around the circle? "Bounds.Extend" will not do it

Once you have created the [circle](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Circle), you can call the getBounds() method on it to get its bounds

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I am wrong but isn't the radius the distance between center point and outer point of a circle? I would go with this.

Comment: I looked at "google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween" but is an "async" function... lots of complexity and I just want the radius